# Unusual Regex Bug in Java

Tags: java, regex

I am having an issue with Regex. So what I want to do is to add character to the start and the end of a search result group. However I am getting a strange bug.

Here is the console log:

```
Start: 0
End: 25
Start: 24
End: 80
C"Hey Topaz how are you?C"D Nathan continues to take a seat and proceeds with, "DI hate that guy"
```

As you can see, the Start is 0 and the End is 25 for the first one. However for the next one, the start is 24. I don't want it. It should be the next quotation group instead. Anyway here is the code:

```
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("\"Hey Topaz how are you?\" Nathan continues to take a seat and proceeds with, \"I hate that guy\"");

    Matcher matcher = quotationPattern.matcher(message);

    while (matcher.find())
    {
        int startIndex = matcher.start();
        int endIndex = matcher.end() + 1;

        System.out.println("Start: " + startIndex);
        System.out.println("End: " + endIndex);
        message.insert(startIndex, 'C');
        message.insert(endIndex, 'D');

    }

    System.out.println(message);
```

I almost forgot. Here is the pattern.

```
protected static Pattern quotationPattern = Pattern.compile("\"(?:\\\\.|[^\"\\\\])*\"");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `endIndex = matcher.end() + 1` - you add `1`. The end of the first pattern and the start of the second are the same point in the `String`. In general; never assume that your bugs are bugs in the language.

Comment: I meant it more like my bug. However that still doen't work. I used +1 so that it was outside the quotation and not inside.

Comment: Perhaps you can manually correct the position of matcher.start() at the end of the loop.

Comment: You're changing the contents of the StringBuilder between one `find()` and the next; Matcher isn't designed for that.  Is there some reason you can't use Matcher's `replaceAll()` method?

Comment: Yes, [Alan is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38092667/unusual-regex-bug-in-java#comment63621462_38092667) - you need to use [`Matcher.appendReplacement/tail`](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/regex/matcher-appendreplacement-example-part-2/).

Comment: I am using that solution now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from:

```
message.insert(startIndex, 'C');
message.insert(endIndex, 'D');
```

This change the contents in `message` and affect result of `Matcher#find()`. After remove these statement, it should work.

The preferred way is to give a immutable string input to `matcher`. You can use `StringBuilder#toString` to return a new `String` and put it into `matcher` to avoid side effect comes from changes in `message`:

```
Matcher matcher = quotationPattern.matcher(message.toString());
```

Comment: Or add one to endIndex after inserting `C`, since that moves everything up one position in the string (after startIndex).

Comment: Aaah that makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(?:\\\\.|[^\"\\\\])*\"");
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder("\"Hey Topaz how are you?\" Nathan continues to take a seat and proceeds with, \"I hate that guy\"");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(message);
int cnt = 0;
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

So, as you can see this is working. The problem with your code is that, you're modifying the original search String, so there's a problem when you search again using m.find() after modifying the String!

This is working for your case :

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"(?:\\\\.|[^\"\\\\])*\"");
String testString = "\"Hey Topaz how are you?\" Nathan continues to take a seat and proceeds with, \"I hate that guy\"";
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(testString);
final Matcher m = p.matcher(testString);
int replaceCount = 0;
while (m.find()) {
        int startIndex = m.start();
        int endIndex = m.end() + 1;
        System.out.println("Start: " + startIndex);
        System.out.println("End: " + endIndex);
        message.insert(startIndex + replaceCount*2, 'C');
        message.insert(endIndex + replaceCount*2, 'D');
        replaceCount += 1;
}
System.out.println(message);
```

[Check here](https://ideone.com/smyTm7)

Since you're modifying the String(testString in my case), so the indices that the `Matcher` returns will be different for your modified String (testString). So keep track of how many times you've added a 'C' and 'D' and increment the `startIndex` and `endIndex` by that count.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. Thank you. I keep forgetting that StringBuilder is immutable.